# Can We Access Multiple Company files through Web Connector?

Tags: quickbooks

I have multiple Quick Books Company files and I want to access those company files at same time with the help of **QB Web connector**.

Can I achieve this? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I achieve this?

At the exact same time? No.

At close to the same time? Yes. QuickBooks only allows you to connect to a single QuickBooks company file at a time. However, the Web Connector is perfectly happy to connect to the first company, exchange data, close that company, and then connect to the second company and follow the same process. Just specify the company file paths in the response to `authenticate` from the Web Connector.

Comment: But if I add application in connector for one company and I choose option (allow access if quick books is not running) then I add another application for second company and choose same option will that not work for my case?

Comment: That will get you access at *close* to the same time (read my post above). It is IMPOSSIBLE to get access to both company files at the exact same time (QuickBooks itself does not support his).

Comment: To be on same side, I can access the Company file data even if it is close.
Quick Books only handle single Company file at a time. am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can access the company file if it's closed. Basically what QuickBooks does in that case is to open it, exchange data, and then close it.